# Undefined index notice HTTP_CLIENT_IP and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Tags: php

```
<?php
$clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$checkForProxy = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(!empty($clientIP)) {
    $ip_address = $http_client_ip;
}
else if(!empty($checkForProxy)) {
    $ip_address = $checkForProxy;
}
else {
    $ip_address = $remote_addr;
}
echo $ip_address;
?>
Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_CLIENT_IP in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\61 IP\better method\a.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\61 IP\better method\a.php on line 3
::1
```

I am getting undefined index error. Its because of these two lines

```
$clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$checkForProxy = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

How do get rid of this why is this occuring is it because i am running it on local host ?

Answer (score 7):

You can check if such keys exist in your `$_SERVER` array:

```
$clientIP = false;
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', $_SERVER))
    $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

$checkForProxy = false;
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',$_SERVER))
    $checkForProxy = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

Comment: this is not python. you should put all code blocks in `{` `}`.

Comment: If I follow `PSR` I should.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by that error you're using `localhost`

If your website is on a web hosting, you can use the `$_SERVER` arrays, BUT when you're using `localhost` you can only use the `getenv()` arrays.

By that it means, instead of using

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

You then use these arrays on `localhost`:

```
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
```

Btw the `mail()` function won't work either, so for that you'd have to set up something like a MTA.

Comment: Why do you have square brackets in `getenv()`? Also, `$_SERVER` is an array, not a function.

Comment: You **can** use `$_SERVER` on localhost. Where, for the love of anything in this world, have you read that you can use getenv() while using localhost server? Also, who told you that mail won't work? What if I set up MTA? Your answer is wrong, that's why I downvoted it. You didn't back up your claims. Fix it, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Yes, if you set up an MTA. If you just dowload XAMPP and run Apache, the server array won't work without setting up anything else, neither will the mail

Comment: Not everyone use Apache or Windows. Your answer is so general that people who stumble upon it will think it's true. You still didn't back up your claims so I'm going to leave the downvote. Bad information is worse than no information.